# removing characters from file

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file with a bunch of events listed:

```
-[test123
-[test456
-[test789
test1011
test1213
```

I'm looking to list the items with -[, but when printing I want to remove the '-['. 
This is what I currently have:

```
f = open("file", "r").readlines()
for line in f:
    if '-[' in line:
        line.lstrip('-[')
token = line.split('_')
print token
```

But I'm not getting the expected result. Can anyone help with where I went wrong?

Comment: ` line=  line.lstrip('-[')
`

Comment: Checking `if '-[' in line` is totally unnecessary, no?

Comment: what do you get ? you want only the items with `-[` ? you maybe have indentation problem ?

Comment: why you split based on underscore? what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

> str.lstrip([chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed.

```
f = open("file", "r").readlines()
for line in f:
    if '-[' in line:
        line = line.lstrip('-[')
    print line  # modified/unmodified line without -[
```

You have to assign modified line to variable line

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the lines starting with `-[`:

```
f = open("file", "r").readlines()
for line in f:
    if '-[' in line:
        line.lstrip('-[')
        token=line.split('_')
        print token
```

If you want all lines but removing `-[`:

```
f = open("file", "r").readlines()
for line in f:
    line.lstrip('-[')
    token=line.split('_')
    print token
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = open("file", "r").readlines()
# to print all lines
lines = [line.lstrip('-[') for line in lines]
# to print only lines with '-['
lines = [line.lstrip('-[') for line in lines if '-[' in line]
```

Now you can iterate over the lines variable and perform whatever operations you want to.